Azure Function Outbound IP Address Issue
I have a situation where I need to move a bunch of node.js scripts from scheduled tasks on an on-prem server, to Azure Functions.  One of them makes an SFTP connection to a vendor-controlled server.  The vendor has whitelisted our public IP for our network, but obviously my script fails when trying to connect from Azure.
The problem is that I don't know if having them whitelist all of the possible azure function ips is a solution, as it seems like they aren't necessarily static.
Does anyone have experience with this type of issue, and have any workarounds that minimize contacting the vendor every time the apps ip address changes?  I think creating a NAT Gateway seems like the best solution so far, but I am wondering if there are better/simpler solutions.
Thanks in advance,
-JD

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938688/how-to-assign-a-static-public-ip-to-azure-function

I think I found a workable solution for this.  I will be putting this under the app service plan (rather than consumption), so I can get access to the azure funcitons advanced networking features.  I created a NAT with a public IP and a virtual network behind the NAT.  Then in the function app, added the virtual network.  This ensures that all network traffic from the function app goes through the NAT public IP. Microsoft has a good writeup HERE. I confirmed that my app was using the public ip with this script:


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log("Node.js HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://ifconfig.me');
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        
        const responseMessage = await response.text();
        
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: responseMessage
        };
    } catch (error) {
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: error.message
        };
   



